# tmux split-window shell command, set env variable before shell start

Tags: shell, tmux

In my tmux config, I have a split window command:

```
bind C-j split-window -v "tmux list-sessions | sed -E 's/:.*$//' | grep -v \"^\"(tmux display-message -p '#S')\"\\\$\" | fzf --reverse | xargs tmux switch-client -t"
```

It will run all the commands in a shell session as defined in split-window of tmux manual. However, my shell contains lots of init scripts that are not related to this custom tmux key binding. And they are slow. Can I set an env variable before `split-window` start a shell session so I can skip some shell init script?

Comment: could you check my proposal?

Comment: @yacc Sorry, I left a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note: Updated in that tmux environment is used now.**

You could set this variable at the beginning of the command pipe. Your shell init scripts could then check its value and act accordingly like skipping some part of the initialisation.

```
bind C-j set-environment TMUXSPLIT 1 \; split-window -v "tmux list-sessions | sed -E 's/:.*$//' | grep -v \"^\"(tmux display-message -p '#S')\"\\\$\" | fzf --reverse | xargs tmux switch-client -t"
```

I assume this is running under Ubuntu which utilizes bash. In your bashrc write something like:

```
if [ "$TMUXSPLIT" = 1 ]; then
    ...
fi
```

Comment: This is a good answer. The downside is that $TMUXSPLIT env var will be present in all new panes, not just the one using `prefix + C-j` key binding.

Comment: It does have the issue @BrunoSutic descript. But if you do `setenv -r TMUXSPLIT` after `split-window`, the env should be removed. But does it have any downside?

Comment: Good thinking. If you remove if with `set-env -r` after `split-window` then I think there's no downside.

Comment: @Daiwai I suggest to post an answer with the full solution once you're done testing and feel comfortable with it.